# In React How to pass Id to another page class component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to pass the Id to another Page using Class components. this.props.match.params.group_Id it returns undefined.Here is my code

```
#page1
<Link to={"/GroupsDetail.js/?group_Id="+item.group_Id}}>Details</Link>

 #page2

submit() {
        let Id= this.props.match.params.group_Id;
        console.log(Id);
        let url = 'http://localhost:0000/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id='+Id;
}
```

Need to pass that Id into API.Please share your Idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const Id = url.searchParams.get("group_Id");
```

Comment: Thank You @Mohaimin. It is working. It is working in Localstorage only ?

Comment: @Vijayaasri do you mean 'localhost'?

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom` only handles the path parts of the URL, it doesn't do anything with queryString parameter other than include them in the [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) object.

> Locations represent where the app is now, where you want it to go, or
> even where it was. It looks like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
>   pathname: '/somewhere',
>   search: '?some=search-string',
>   hash: '#howdy',
>   state: {
>     [userDefined]: true
>   }
> }
> ```

Access the `location` prop and pass the `search` property to a new `URLSearchParams` to parse the queryString.

```
submit() {
  const { location } = this.props;
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  const Id = query.get('group_Id');;
  console.log(Id);
  let url = 'http://localhost:0000/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id='+Id;
}
```

If you wanted to keep the group id on the route's match params then you'll need to define the route path like `path="/GroupsDetail.js/:Id"`, and link to it as `` <Link to={`/GroupsDetail.js/${item.group_Id}`}>Details</Link> ``.